# How to make transition from one Dialog to another Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I have bottom-sheet when I tap on button DialogFragment appears in the Bottom Sheet. But When I tap on the button in this DialogFragment, I don't swap them. I.e I want to make a transition between DialogFragments. How to solve this problem?

> This my code in Bottom Sheet:

```
public void imageButton(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // before
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_metka_aims);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

}
```

}

Comment: explain what you want to achieve, as it is unclear